# Angularx-flatpickr call changeMonth - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, flatpickr

I'm using `angularx-flatpickr@6.1.0` I need to change calendar month from code. According to [documentation](https://flatpickr.js.org/instance-methods-properties-elements/) there should be a method called `changeMonth`. I tried getting calendar Instance from code but it seems like a normal HTML element not a flatpickr. Do anybody knows if there's a way to call it? Or I should dump the wrapper and start to use pure library?

Here's what I've tried

```
<span
  type="text"
  mwlFlatpickr
  [(ngModel)]="selectedDate"
  [altInput]="true"
  [convertModelValue]="true"
  [inline]="true"
  (flatpickrDayCreate)="dayCreate($event)"
  #calendar
></span>

export class CalendarComponent {
  @ViewChild('calendar') calendar: Instance; // i tried ElementRef, any, FlatPickrDirective nothing got this method
  selectedDate: Date;

  constructor(private flatepickr: FlatpickrDefaults) {} // this services comes with wrapper but doesnt have any methods.

  dayCreate($e) {
    console.log($e);
  }
}
```

Sorry I'm asking it here but the repo doesn't have issues.

Comment: i ended up dumping wrapper and using pure library

Comment: I'm also looking for how to get the instance in the component class

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late, but after some time I finally got it to work! It turns out that we can get the instance by listening to one of the events emiited by the `mwlFlatpickr` directive. Please check [mwlFlatpickr docs](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angularx-flatpickr/docs/interfaces/FlatPickrOutputOptions.html#source):

```
@Output()
 flatpickrReady: EventEmitter<FlatPickrOutputOptions> = new 
 EventEmitter();

export interface FlatPickrOutputOptions {
   selectedDates: Date[];
   dateString: string;
   instance: any;
}
```

Thus, we can get the instance by saving it in the component after the calendar is ready and the event is emitted.

This worked for me:

.html file:

```
<input #calendar
    (flatpickrReady)="calendarReady($event)"
    mwlFlatpickr>
```

.ts file:

```
calendarInstance: any; // variable to store the instance reference
calendarReady(event) {
 this.calendarInstance = event.instance;
 // call methods from instance 
 // this.calendarInstance.toggle()
}
```

Hope it helps!